# category of linear maps

Tags: category-theory

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces. Let's define a category whose objects are linear map $f:V\to W$ and morphisms from $f$ to $g$ are pair of linear maps $(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha:V\to V,\beta :W\to W$ such that $g \circ\alpha = \beta \circ f$.

1. Does this category have some special name?
2. If $f_i$ are indexed family of objects, is there product of them in this category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for this category having cartesian products: it's a very strange question, but the answer is 'no', unless both $V$ and $W$ are trivial ($0$-dimensional).

The basic problem can be illustrated by asking: does this category have a terminal object? Suppose $f: V \to W$ is terminal. This means that for any $h: V \to W$, there is exactly one pair of morphisms $g_1: V \to V$, $g_2: W \to W$ such that $g_2 \circ h = f \circ g_1$. Of course, by taking $g_1$ and $g_2$ both to be zero maps, there is always at least one such pair. But suppose we consider when $h: V \to W$ is the zero map. In that case every pair $(0, g_2)$ works. Thus we get uniqueness of the pair only if $W$ is trivial. But then $f = 0$, and now every pair $(g_1, 0)$ works, and we get uniqueness only if also $V$ is trivial.

The basic principle is that this category of linear maps admits products insofar as the full subcategory consisting of the single object $V$ (and similarly, the one for $W$) has products. For example, the category of linear maps has binary products if and only if we have isomorphisms $\phi: V \to V \times V$ and $\psi: W \to W \times W$, which is the case iff $V$ and $W$ are infinite-dimensional (let's agree to ignore cases where $V$ or $W$ is trivial). I.e., the composites

$$p_i = (V \stackrel{\phi}{\to} V \times V \stackrel{\pi_i}{\to} V), i = 1, 2$$

give product projections $p_1, p_2: V \to V$ in the full subcategory determined by $V$. If $q_1, q_2: W \to W$ are similar product projections for $W$, then the pairs $(p_1, q_1)$, $(p_2, q_2)$ furnish product projections for the category of linear maps. This is not hard to check. Of course, by cardinality considerations, we cannot have *arbitrary* products for any full subcategory determined by $V$ (again, except for the trivial case), since there will be no isomorphism $V \to V^S$ for a sufficiently high power $S$, and this carries over to the category of linear maps as well.

Comment: But are you sure that the product does not exists? I tried it with similar arguments, but I failed to show it.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure. I can edit in an argument later about that (a little tied up with something else at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

This is the morphism category that is associated to any category.  If you notice, the morphisms in the morphism category are natural transformations.

Comment: It's often called the arrow category. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category

Comment: About the product, objects of the category are linear maps from $V$ to $W$, where $V,W$ are fixed. So Isn't it different from product of vector spaces? The product of $f_i:V \to W$ should be also a linear map $f:V\to W$.

Comment: @Gobi I hadn't realized that $V$ and $W$ were fixed.  I thought you were just saying that your category was morphisms between any two vector spaces.  I will remove that from my answer.